# Are all lines in a rails method run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def login_required
        unless current_user
            store_location
            flash[:notice] = I18n.t('must_be_logged_in')
            redirect_to new_user_session_path
            return false
        end
    end
```

I have this method in a rails app. My question is when will the line `return false` ever be run?

The line before it says `redirect_to new_user_session_path`.

```
def admin_required
        return false if login_required == false
        unless current_user.admin?
            store_location
            flash[:notice] = t('must_be_admin')
            redirect_to new_user_session_url
            return false
        end
    end
```

For clarification this method requires `login_required == false` (or true).. how will the first method ever return false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What troubles you is the fact that a `#redirect_to` is not a return statement : it marks response as having to redirect somewhere else, but it does not stop the execution flow.

```
redirect_to root_path # executed
puts "foo"            # executed
return                # executed
puts "bar"            # not executed
```

The reason for that is actually obvious when you think about `#redirect_to` implementation. `redirect_to` is a method implemented by rails, not a core language keyword, like `return`.

Now, imagine you have to implement `#redirect_to` yourself. You would do something like that :

```
def redirect_to( url )
  response.redirect = url
end
```

Now, you call that method in an action :

```
def index
  redirect_to root_path
  puts "foo"
end
```

Obviously, here, your second instruction in `#index` will be called as well, because your `#redirect_to` method have no mean[1] to inform its caller it should stop execution.

Note that this applies to `#render` as well : they are simple methods, not instruction flow controlling keywords.

[1] Actually, we could think of a mean to interrupt execution flow : throwing exceptions catched somewhere by a class handling redirections, but that's generally considered bad design to use exception to control flow when there aren't actual error.

Comment: Wow, you have actually changed the way I think about a part of rails thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Returning false will just stop the action's code execution there and then. You'll also see lines like this

```
return redirect_to :action => :index
```

or

```
redirect_to :action => :index and return
```

They all mean the same thing.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I just don't understand how you could ever get past the line `redirect_to new_user_session_path`. Each time the method is run isn't that where the method's code execution stops?... because you have been redirected?

Comment: The HTTP Headers are only generated when all the statements in the action are executed successfully. redirect_to would generate the redirect http headers but it will not send it until all the statements are executed. If redirect_to is the last statment you never need return statements.

Comment: So what your saying is that all the lines in the method are executed even though the second last line redirects the user?... so in effect `return false` happens *every* time the block is run?

Comment: Yes, but in your case since redirect_to is the last statement, you don't need return false, it will be redirected without it.